# 301 redirect not working with %20 in the old path

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301

This 301 redirect doesn't work with the spaces as %20

```
  Redirect 301 /Content/userfiles/Private%20Dining%20Brochure%20WEB.pdf

  Redirect 301 /Content/userfiles/Private%20Dining%20Brochure%20WEB.pdf http://www.lortolan.com/section/5/1/michelin-private-dining
```

Should go to this page
http://www.lortolan.com/section/5/1/michelin-private-dining

Answer (score 0):

Is it `.htaccess`? Then try a space instead of `%20`, and quote it.

```
Redirect 301 "/Content/userfiles/Private Dining Brochure WEB.pdf" http://www.lortolan.com/section/5/1/michelin-private-dining
```